# extract equation used to get the best fit using Lattice (panel.smoother) or ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, lattice, stat

I have 100+ files with similar data following almost the same trend. I have managed to obtained best fits for all of them but now i want to compare that to a theoretical argument. To put in other words, I would like to generate one equation for the best fit curves I have generated using the experimental data; the equation would work for any random values in a specific range and produce a similar curve as before of course with a few errors.

Code:

```
set.seed(42)
x <-sort(round(runif(10,0,53)))   ## random x values
y <- runif(10,0,400)              ## random y values
data1 <-  data.frame(y=y,x=x)     ## creating a data frame
```

Now I either use `lattice` like below:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot(y ~ x,data=data1,par.settings = ggplot2like(),
                   panel = function(x,y,...){
                     panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
                   })+ layer(panel.smoother(y ~ x, se = FALSE, span = 0.5))
```

Or `ggplot` as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

[image]

I would just like to know its equation or may be just a few parameters of the curve (coefficients, standard error values, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smoothers generally are more complex than you appear to understand. They are usually only defined locally, so there is no global equation as there might be with a polynomial fit. The `panel.smoother` function uses the `loess` smoother by default and there is no equation in the object returned from your call to `xyplot`. Rather there is a call to the `panel.smoother` function kept in the `lay` node of the panel-node:

```
 myplot <- xyplot(y ~ x,data=data1,par.settings = ggplot2like(),
               panel = function(x,y,...){
                 panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
               })+ layer(panel.smoother(y ~ x, se = FALSE, span = 0.5))
 get('lay', envir = environment(myplot$panel))
#-------------
[[1]]
expression(panel.smoother(y ~ x, se = FALSE, span = 0.5))
attr(,"under")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"superpose")
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "layer"   "trellis"
```

This shows you what is produced when that expression gets evaluated:

```
mysmooth <- loess(y~x)
str(mysmooth)
#--------
List of 17
 $ n        : int 10
 $ fitted   : num [1:10] 176 312 275 261 261 ...
 $ residuals: Named num [1:10] 6.78 -24.43 98.8 -159.25 -75.9 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 ----------- omitting remaider of output------------
```

I used the `xyplot`-smoother because trying to find code details inside a ggplot function-result is even more complex than is that task applied to a lattice-object. Moral of this story: If you want a function of particular complexity and definable characteristic, then use a suitable spline function, such as `spline` or `psspline` in survival or `rcs` in rms.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually did not understand the functionality of smoother before your post. The result out of str() is exactly what I was looking for. Using the values, I think I can create the equation I need. splines() seems to work fine too. Thank you again.